# Internet <-(Wifi)-> Mac <-(BlueTooth)-> Another Mac: How?

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, bluetooth

I have two Macs, one of which is connected to the Internet via WiFi. I need the other Mac to use the Internet as well. It doesn't work via the Ethernet cable (probably because of the bad cable; I cannot get another one here), so I want to do it Bluetooth. I have set up Bluetooth sharing on the donor Mac no problem:

[image]

It seems that the recipient Mac doesn't have an option to reuse the donor connection - it can only browse to the public folder. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't close a question by saying "is now closed" :) Please use the "Answer your Question" button below to add an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, we were missing a setting to use a "serial port" Bluetooth-PDA-sync:

[Missing setting http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitpic/photos/full/369607344.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJF3XCCKACR3QDMOA&Expires=1313009998&Signature=9j81uxSOw%2F%2F1Mw1V589Ul5dAqG0%3D](http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitpic/photos/full/369607344.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJF3XCCKACR3QDMOA&Expires=1313009998&Signature=9j81uxSOw%2F%2F1Mw1V589Ul5dAqG0%3D)

Strangely enough, this setting worked once but we couldn't get it to work since then :-(